# Adding data to Empty Nested Dictionary in Python 3

Tags: dictionary, networkx, defaultdict

Am new to Python; trying to learn the concept of dictionary while building / operating a network graph. Looks like I am not getting it right.

I have a CSV file of following format:

RC11,RC12,RC13,RC14,RC15,RC16,RC17,RC18,RC19,RC110 RC21,RC22,RC23,RC24,RC25,RC26,RC27,RC28,RC29,RC210 RC31,RC32,RC33,RC34,RC35,RC36,RC37,RC38,RC39,RC310

I read this file to create a network MultiDiGraph using networkx package, where the first two columns represents the two nodes of an edge and the remaining columns constitues various edge attributes that is stored in an attribute dictionary. Using these values I create an entry into a previously initialized nested dictionary, named 'moves'.

```
# create an empty nested dictionary
movesTree = lambda: defaultdict(movesTree)
moves = movesTree()   # based on a suggested solution [here][1]

# read the CSV file using pandas (as pd) package's read_csv()
columns = list(pd.read_csv(fileURI, sep=',', nrows=0).columns)    # just headers
routingData = pd.read_csv(fileURI, sep=',').dropna()   # entire file

# add edge to the previously created MultiDiGraph routingNetwork
for i, elrow in routingData.iterrows():
    routingNetwork.add_edge(elrow[0], elrow[1], attr_dict=elrow[2:].to_dict())

    # add values from the row to the dictionary moves
    # first 6 values in the row forms the unique key
    # last 5 values correspond to various attributes for that key (from header list)
    moves[elrow[0]][elrow[1]][elrow[2]][elrow[3]][elrow[4]][elrow[5]] = [(columns[6], elrow[6]), (columns[7], elrow[7]), (columns[8], elrow[8]), (columns[9], elrow[9]), (columns[10], elrow[10])]

print(list(moves))
```

Unfortunately, the print() above only output the deduped list of the nodes, minus the terminal node. What am I doing wrong?

NOTE: in reality, at each node the moves will need to hold the data for only the out-edges of that node. Before I go to that logic, I was testing the above statement syntax and output and got stuck

Comment: The logic is currently unclear, can you please explain the logic and give the exact expected output (that matches the given input)? (maybe use a bit less columns if needed for clarity). Also your CSV doesn't have a header, is it expected?

Comment: @mozway yes, the CSV has a header row, that I read and assign to a list named "columns" The overall logic for this part is simple. Reading the CSV to construct the MultiDiGraph named routingNetwork. In this the edges are added to the graph using the the first two columns that designates the two nodes - From_Node and To_Node of the directed Edge. In this graph there are multiple edges possible between two nodes. In the CSV the remainder of the columns (3 to 10) are various attributes of the defining edge. The edge uniqueness is defined by the combination of first six column values. (1 of 2)

Comment: (2 of 2) the first two columns define the direction while the other four defines other unique characteristics. Think of it like a path from "Point A" to "Point B" by "Road" with "Transporter A" via their "Car A" at "Full occupancy." Each quoted data represent a column. The remaining 5 columns define other values for this path - Total Distance, Total Time, Total Cost, Total Emission, etc. Depending on the path travelled we will use these data for other downstream purposes. At any point, this single edge is one of many "move" options. I am trying to create a list of such options for each node

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the mistake(s). Changing the last two lines as follows, gives me the desired output. The mistake was in the improper way of writing the composite key to the dictionary "moves."

```
    moves[(elrow[0], elrow[1], elrow[2], elrow[3], elrow[4], elrow[5])] = elrow[6:].to_dict()
print(moves)
```